# Graphics Processor for gaming under $250

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards

> **CPU info**
>
> > Name: *Intel Pentium G2030*
> >     Code Name: *Ivy Bridge*
> >     Generation: *3rd*
> >     Core frequency: *~3GHz*
> >     Cores, Threads: *2, 2*
> >     Max TDP: *55W*
> >     Graphics: *Intel HD Graphics*

I know very well it's a low-end CPU. I can't play high graphics games. Actually I can, but I need to minimize the graphics settings. These are the settings I usually set:

> Resolution: *960x720(4:3) or 1024x576(16:9), [Native Resolution: 1920x1080]*
>   FPS: *30*
>   Refresh Rate: *60*
>   Fullscreen: *ON*
>   VSync: *OFF*
>   Texture Quality: *MEDIUM*
>   HDR Filter: *OFF*
>   Shadow Quality: *LOW (if "OFF" isn't in the option)*
>   Motion Blur: *OFF*
>   Glare Level: *OFF*
>   Depth of Field: *OFF*
>   FXAA: *ON*

As you can see, I will turn it off or select "low" if there are more options. My motherboard is made for Intel 3rd generation core i7/i5/i3/pentium/celeron processors. I would like to have suggestions about which processors I should buy without over the budget. I'm a completely idiot to hardwares btw.

***Budget: $200*** (max. $250)

I want to stick with my current [motherboard](http://www.ecs.com.tw/website2008/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1366&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=103&LanID=0), and I want the best processor for gaming that I can effort.

Comment: Before you go and buy a graphics card, we should know what kind of case and power supply your system has. Also, your motherboard needs to have a 16x PCI-E slot. Is it a factory-built PC from, say, Dell? Or was it a custom-built one you (or someone else) built?

Comment: @Justin_T Yes, it has a PCI-E slot, it's a custom-built from the one who I bought from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a GPU, not a CPU for gaming. Is there a reason you need to buy a new CPU? If not, spend that $200-$250 on a GPU instead.

You want something like this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150761

Instead of dealing with piss-poor low graphics, you'll be able to turn up most settings to maximum for many games.

Intel Integrated Graphics are suitable for desktop environments (very low graphics processing requirements) or video rendering (for software like OpenBroadcaster.)

Comment: How can I find the graphics card on my pc? Is that Intel HD Graphics?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea recommending a 380x to pair with a relatively low end dual core CPU. An i3 dual core? Sure. Maybe even the g3258 AE. But the g2030 appears to be a decent amount slower then those, so OP could be in a bottlenecking situation.

Comment: @HappyFace Intel HD Graphics does do graphics yes. You may not have an actual GPU. It would be sticking out of your motherboard and look like the thing I linked.

Comment: @patricksweeney Most games still don't fully utilize more than 2 cores. There is a possibility of a CPU bottleneck for some games but going from using an Intel HD iGPU to anything at all will probably blow his mind. He can upgrade the CPU later as needs arise.

Comment: Right, but the IPC for something like the g2030 is a lot lower than an i3 6100, which is still a dual core CPU. What I'm saying is that something like a 370 might be a better choice, being a good deal cheaper and probably won't be "held back" as much as a 380x. Heck, even the 380 is a lot cheaper than the 380x. That being said, if OP has the budget it's not like there's any real harm going overkill on the GPU.

Comment: So, if I pick graphics card, which is better? R9 380X or R7 370 (both 4GB)? Though, R7 370 is lot cheaper than 380x, but I don't see differences in specifications. Well, one is DDR5 and another is GDDR5. Is this the reason why it's so much difference in price? Why? Thx for the answer.

Comment: @HappyFace the reason for the difference in price is: R9 380x has twice as many stream processors (2048). While R7 370 has 1024. More processors generally means better performance. The better overall for you would be the R9. If or when you will decide to upgrade your CPU the R9 will be better suited to keep up and even probably deliver a bit more performance since it probably wont be bottlenecked with a better CPU.

Comment: @AndriyLysak Ok, I don't need a powerful GPU that run for example gta5 or just cause 3 smoothly in 60fps in full hd. If it's not over the budget, then I will get it. The problem is I don't know how well the gpu do, if a cheaper gpu will run the games smoothly in 60fps, I definitely will get that.

Comment: @HappyFace this might help: http://www.techspot.com/review/1114-vram-comparison-test/ also try to google for more benchmarks before deciding on a card.

Comment: @HappyFace If you're not displeased by the price, you won't be displeased by the performance gains of the 380x over the 370. A 370 would be adequate for you but again, if you don't mind the price difference, a 380x is better.